# How to think about a homeomorphism?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Two disjoint circles in the Euclidean space are homeomorphic to two circles interlocked without touching each other. My professor said that to a topologist they are the same thing. I don't understand why. What properties of a space are of concern to a topologist and what are things he is not interested in?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They are the "same thing" in the sense that there is a homeomorphism between them. They look different to you because you are considering how the two components are embedded in $\mathbb R^3$. The circles don't "know" about the embedding in the ambient space you see.

There are other ways in which they are *not* the same thing, but those involve more than just comparing them as topological spaces. You know intuitively that in some way there is a difference (otherwise, handcuffs wouldn't work), but he is speaking from a purely topological perspective.

Answer (score 8):

Homeomorphisms capture the *intrinsic* properties of a topological space.

The distinction you want to make is about *extrinsic* properties: how the two circles are *embedded* in euclidean space. One way to phrase this precisely is by considering the *complement* in the two cases. These complements are not homeomorphic.

Check out [link theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_%28knot_theory%29).