# Homeomorphic or Homotopic

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, differential-topology, homotopy-theory, geometric-topology

> Q1: Are the Fig (a) and (b), the equivalence "="   is **Homeomorphic or Homotopic?**

[image]

ps. for details of the figures see [Ref here](http://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-th/9609049.pdf).

I learned that "The characterization of a homeomorphism often leads to confusion with the concept of homotopy, which is actually defined as a continuous deformation, but from one function to another, rather than one space to another. In the case of a homeomorphism, envisioning a continuous deformation is a mental tool for keeping track of which points on space X correspond to which points on Y—one just follows them as X deforms. In the case of homotopy, the continuous deformation from one map to the other is of the essence, and it is also less restrictive, since none of the maps involved need to be one-to-one or onto. Homotopy does lead to a relation on spaces: homotopy equivalence."

> Q2: Does **Homeomorphic** **necessary** imply the **Homotopic equivalence** of space? So Homeomorphic is stronger restricted condition than Homotopic?

Comment: I am thinking that both Fig (a) and (b) "=" are  Homeomorphic, thus necessarily Homotopic.

Comment: Homeomorphic spaces do have the same homotopy type. This is easily seen by considering the homeomorphism and its inverse. Their composition is the identity function on either of the spaces, which is well..... homotopic equivalent to the identity.

Comment: Spaces can be of the same homotopy type but still be not homeomorphic. So in that sense it is a weaker condition.

Comment: Two 3D objects that are homeomorphic need not be transformable (within 3-space) into each other. That would require that the presumed homeomorphism from one to the other is homotopic to its embedding (both viewed as functions into the topological space $\mathbb R^3$ rather than the objects themselves). - For example two interlocked circles are homeomorphic to two noninterlocked circles, but you cannot transform  them; same for a knotted and an unknotted torus

Comment: Yes, an example of that would be: Two circles interlocked without touching each other are homeomorphic to two disjoint circles

Comment: Maps can be *homotopic*, spaces can be **homotopy equivalent**. It's a notational distinction that helps when communicating these things. If $X$ and $Y$ are homeomorphic then $X$ and $Y$ are homotopy equivalent, but not necessarily the converse.

Comment: Dear Panda Bear, are you sure: "Two circles interlocked without touching each other are homeomorphic to two disjoint circles", I thought they are homotopy equivalent but not homeomorphic???

Comment: Yes I am sure. I had a problem understanding that too. I asked a question about it. Check out my profile.

Comment: Also, don't forget to put @username at the beginning, or else I won't know you replied to me. I don't have to put it, because this is your post. You will automatically get notifications about any activity on it.

Comment: It is here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homotopy#Homotopy_equivalence

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/746545/79069