# How to prove that no homeomorphism $\mathbb R^3\rightarrow \mathbb R^3$ can unlink circles.

Tags: general-topology

There are already a few questions such as [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/808239/two-interlocked-circles-are-homeomorphic-to-two-noninterlocked-circles) where it is discussed that you can in fact unlink circles homeomorphically, but you **can not** give a homeomorphism $\mathbb R^3\rightarrow \mathbb R^3$ that unlinks circles. This is intuitively true, but how can we formally prove that there is no such homeomorphism?

Comment: One usually proves that the complement of two circles in $\mathbb R^3$ has different homology groups depending on wether the groups are linked or not

Comment: If I recall correctly, Hatcher proves it by deformation retracting the two complements to spaces which are "clearly not" homotopy equivalent. Was it that one had abelian fundamental group and the other one not? Don't remember exactly.